# PHP echo array value without looping

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code which works perfectly fine to give me the name of the customer with the ID of 10:

```
foreach($customer_list as $row) {
    if ($row->CUSTOMER_ID == 10)
    echo $row->NAME;
}
```

Is there a way I can do this more directly, without the foreach loop and if statement? I'd like to do something like:

```
echo $customer_list[CUSTOMER_ID][10]->NAME;
```

But I don't know the syntax or if it's even possible.

Comment: Where did you get the `$customer_list` variable? Database call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `array_filter`  It will return an array of customers whose ID is 10. We then select the first match (the only match probably) and access the `NAME` property.

```
$name = reset( array_filter(
            $customer_list,function($c){return $c->CUSTOMER_ID === 10;}
    ))->NAME;
```

The cleaner approach is to factor it out, into a separate function:

```
$getCustName = function($list,$id){
    return reset( array_filter(
        $list,
        function($c) use ($id) {return $c->CUSTOMER_ID === $id;}
    ))->NAME;
};
```

Then you can get the name easily with just one line:

```
$name = $getCustName($customer_list,10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [php array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) method. 
Basically you need to pass a function which will check value of customer_Id and returns the element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

you can add your code inside a function and then call that function when you need the name. I am assuming you have unique customer ID's.

```
function getCustName($customers,$id){
  if(count($customers)>0){
    foreach($customers as $row) {
       if ($row->CUSTOMER_ID == $id)
       return $row->NAME;
    }
  } else{
      return false;
  } 
}
```

Now if you need to get customer name just call the function

```
echo getCustName($customer_list,10);
```